# What are practical ways to simplify/represent $0,n,0,n,0,n...$ sequences to make a power series more efficient?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, power-series

Suppose I have a series in the form of $$ \sum_{k=0}^{n}((-1)^n+1)x^n$$

This will look like $S_n = 2+0+2x^2+0+2x^4+0...$

How do I re-index the sum so that either the $((-1)^n+1)$ term is no longer two terms, but just one term as a function of n so that I can pair it with $z^n$ such that;
if $u = ((-1)^{n}+1)$, then $S_n = (uz)^{n}$? Do I need some kind of step function or is there a less awkward way to write it, using only functions that need not be constrained to descrete number systems (f(n)=2n is instantly interpolable to the complex number system)

And, would it be correct to just re-rewrite it as $2 \sum_{k=0}^{n}x^{2n}$?

How does one prove that second form with index notation? Is there a way to do it without induction? I would think whatever method of proof for it should be applicable to other kinds of $a_k$ terms, since $x^{2k}$ is easy to work with.

Comment: when you wrote $x^n$ did you mean $x^k$?

Comment: Yes <insert useless blank space because SE told me to>.

Comment: No, 
 $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}((-1)^k+1)x^k \neq  2 \sum_{k=0}^{n}x^{2k}.$$
 The left hand side is a polynomial of degree $n$ or $n-1$, depending on the parity of $n$. The right hand side is a polynomial of degree $2n$.

I don't know what you are looking for, because I don't know what 'efficient' means

Comment: But only every polynomial with an odd degree vanishes, so how *couldn't* the result be a collection of even polynomials for any integer index?

Comment: Yes, which is not a contradiction. If $n$ is odd, then LHS is degree $n-1$ (hence, a bunch of even polynomials)

Comment: Are you referring to a trivial substitution to a dummy variable? Because this post seems to affirm what I'm saying https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1550762/spliting-into-even-and-odd-n-sum that you can in fact split a sum into even and odd terms, and since the odd terms go to zero, you're left with even terms.

Comment: what? I'm not preferring (referring?) to anything. I'm just stating and proving the non-equality I wrote down

Comment: Yes, you are left with even terms. This is consistent with what I said. The number of even terms is stated in the answer that you consider "awkward"

Comment: So in other words yes, the technicality you were implicitly hinting at is that it needs to be re-indexed through some substitution such that the index counts from a new lower bound to a modified upper bound since technically just the even terms is no longer rewritten as a 1-1 correspondence with the original index. But, simply that statement doesn't prove the end result.

Comment: I pointed out exactly what I wanted to point out : $LHS  ≠ RHS$. That sentence is already what the answer below is doing. How you "need" to fix it would depend on a better understanding of what you mean by "efficient". If you want an equality sign, then the $n$ in both sides needs to mean the same thing.

Comment: Efficiency means I don't have to arbitrarily inspect each term to decide to floor it or not, that neither me nor a computer has to do the expression's work of deciding a number, that I can instead use actual algebra or analysis. And if you try to interpolate it with conventional functions, you have to represent it as a very complicated integral or series that is too niche and complicated to be generally useful. Imagine dealing with infinite step functions instead of a nice simple function like $2m$; that is the flooring function for you.

Comment: I would be exceptionally surprised if there wasn't a way to write this sum as simply a sum of even terms but for a finite bound as this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1550762/spliting-into-even-and-odd-n-sum implies. The problem then is keeping the upper bound the same.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to interpolate the floor of $n/2$? $n$ is an integer, checking the evenness or oddness of an integer is incredibly efficient for computers already. And $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ is a "finite bound". Hope you find what you're looking for, either its impossible or I don't understand you

Comment: Why would I want a floor function at all? That's what you're ignoring for some reason.

Comment: Because its virtually baked into your function, and any other way of writing it would be just doing so for the sake of not naming He-Who-Should-Not-Be-Named... for instance 
$$ \left\lfloor \frac n2 \right\rfloor  = \frac n2 + \frac{(-1)^{n} - 1}4$$
but I doubt this is any more efficient.

Comment: You can pointlessly throw your hands up and say $cos( pi*x)+i sin(pi*x)$ is "baked in" to an alternating series, or, you can merely rewrite it as $(-1)^n$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{k=0}^n ((-1)^k + 1) x^k = 2\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} x^{2k}$$

Comment: Something as awkward and discontinuous as a flooring function, especially in the bound, is what I was trying to avoid though. The reason why sequences such as Euler numbers or Cauchy numbers or Bernouli numbers are useful is because they have specific combinatoric properties that can be leveraged recursively, but with a flooring function, I don't see any such advantage. Perhaps representing it as trigonometric functions would be more helpful.

Comment: @TeXnichal, it sounds like an [X-Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). If you ask about the true underlying problem, you're more likely to get useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

If your notion of efficiency allows for the Iverson bracket ($[p]=1$ if $p$ is true, $0$ if $p$ is false), then
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^n ((-1)^k + 1)x^k = 2 \sum_{k=0}^n [2|k] x^k = 2 \sum_{k=0}^n ([2|k] x)^k
\end{equation}
where $2|k$ is the statement that 2 divides evenly into $k$.

Comment: But instead of a function that, in the best case scenario can *only* be interpreted discretely without convoluted trigonometric integrals, is there instead a way you could rewrite the sum in this form https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1550762/spliting-into-even-and-odd-n-sum except instead of an infinite upper index, you would use the original and finite upper index?